# Windows event id 4673 audit Failed attempt to perform a privileged operation

Tags: windows, logging

I am consistently receiving this error message from agents, and I am receiving a significant number of them daily from a single agent, while the other agents are also receiving the same error message.

```
"Failed attempt to perform a privileged operation." 

Windows Agentdata.win.eventdata.objectServer
Securitydata.win.eventdata.privilegeList
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilegedata.win.eventdata.processId
0x3a64

data.win.eventdata.processName
C:\\Users\\M\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Teams\\current\\Teams.exedata.win.eventdata.subjectDomainName
CORPdata.win.eventdata.subjectLogonId
0x11ecd4data.win.eventdata.subjectUserName
XXXXdata.win.eventdata.subjectUserSid
S-1-5-21-2379723809-854683683-3710391016-1556data.win.system.channel
Security
```

Could you kindly provide us with your guidance on whether this is a legitimate event or not?